# I need an event trigger for a radio button for when it is unchecked because another button is checked

Tags: javascript

I need an event trigger for a radio button for when it is unchecked because another button is checked.

The code below should demonstrate my dilemma.

If you will notice, there is an onchange event trigger atttached to each radio button and checkbox in the html code. In theory a change in state from checked to unchecked should fire the onchange event.

This happens as expected with the check boxes. If you check one, you get the alert, 'Your item is changed to checked'. If you uncheck it, you get the alert, 'Your item is changed to unchecked'.

With the radio buttons, when you check button one, you get, as expected, the alert, 'Your item is changed to checked' since the button changed from unchecked to checked. However, when you check the second button and the first radio button is changed from checked to unchecked the "onchange" event trigger does not fire and the 'else' alert is not triggered.

So this issue for me is what event is triggered when a radio button gets unchecked by another button being checked?

I appreciate everyone's assistance on this.

--Kenoli

```
    <html>
<head>
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript">

function clickAction() {

    //alert ('Your item changed');

    if (this.checked == true) {alert ('Your item is changed to checked');}

    else if (this.checked == false) {alert('Your item is changed to unchecked');}

}



</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function initializeToggles() {

    var button1= document.getElementById('button1');
    button1.onchange = clickAction;

    var box1= document.getElementById('box1');
    box1.onchange = clickAction;

    var box2= document.getElementById('box2');
    box2.onchange = clickAction;

}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = initializeToggles;</script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="testRadio" id="button1" >Button one<br/>
<input type="radio" name="testRadio" id="button2" >Button two<br/><br/>

<input type="checkbox" name="testCheckbox" id="box1" >Box one<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="testCheckbox" id="box2" >Box two<br/><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

I came here looking for a quick solution for this type of problem, and nuc's answer helped me come up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this);
    $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
      if $(this).attr('id') != selected.attr('id') {
        console.log( $(this).attr('value') + ' was deselected because ' + selected.attr('value') + ' was clicked.')
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This won't actually work for multiple radio groups - you need to check the name attribute to make sure they're actually in the same group.

Comment: you're right... it would require some slight modification.  feel free to edit the answer if you've adapted it to handle multiple groups.

Answer (score 2):

There is no event for when a radio button gets unchecked. You might be able to use the `onpropertychange` event, however that's not a standardised event so it might only work in Internet Explorer.

The safest way would be to take care of that in the onchange event. If you want to know which radio button was unchecked, you would have to keep a reference to the currently checked element in a variable.

Comment: Thanks.  That answers my question.  I guess I can create a variable of 'checked' elements and walk through it to reset those elements.  Seems like with so much AJAX these days, an "onunset' event for unchecking a radio button would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified rthbound's code to handle a group of radio input's, in my case enclosed in a `<table>`.  But this could easily altered for a `<div>`.  Also this code is more compliant with jQuery 1.9.  A common class would be better, to take the class from the selected radio and find other radio inputs with the same class, but I'm working with ASP.NET and this is quicker and easier for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("change", "input[type='radio']", function () {
        var selected = $(this);
        $(this).closest("table").find("input[type='radio']").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("id") !== selected.attr("id")) {
                console.log($(this).attr("value") + " was deselected because " + selected.attr("value") + " was clicked.");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue in a generic way:

whenever a radio button is changed:

1. if they were triggered by this system - we don't want unending loops.
2. find all its radio button friends
3. trigger change on them

then I can test for whether the radio button was checked or unchecked.

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function(e, by_other) {
        if (!by_other) {
          $("input[type='radio'][name='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']")
            .not(this)
            .trigger('change', true)
        }
    }
}
```

(I did translate it from coffeescript to javascript for ya'll.)